# How to UPDATE a String with a int (+1) and convert back to String

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following problem.

An ID is stored in a field this field is declared as char(3).

I would like to rewrite this field and always count high by one from 001. 
and save this value back to char(3). The leading zeros must be back on.

In addition, the value of the previous row must be determined.

It is a foreign software so I have to live with the realities.

Can someone help me here?

```
Old Value 
char(3)
001 

New Value
char(3)
001+1 = 002

UPDATE example SET id = id + 1 WHERE  // Doenst work cause it is a string
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lpad()`:

```
UPDATE example
    SET id = LPAD(id + 1, 3, '0')
    WHERE . . .;
```

However, if your `id` is a number, you should probably store it as a number.  In fact, I would recommend an auto-increment column, if that fits your needs.

Then you can use a view or generated column to return it as a string.